# Rails pg database: schema_migrations empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am trying to deploy a new release of a project to my staging server, but the schema_migrations table in the database is inexplicably empty.

It is now trying to run all migrations while deploying, causing issues since the other tables exist and are intact.

Instead of dropping/recreating the database and losing all my data(though inconvenient, a valid option), is it possible to generate the schema_migrations table without dropping?

Comment: How many migrations are there? You can connect to the DB and add them manually.

Answer (score 0):

Two points:

1. There's nothing wrong with deleting migrations that aren't needed anymore, you're not supposed to keep them around forever.
2. You can manually update the `schema_migrations` table if you have to.

As far as **(1)** goes, I delete migrations (provided they've been applied everywhere) that are old than a month or so. Keeping around years of clutter in `db/migrate` is pointless. Migrating down and then back up tends to be more of a mess than it is worth for all but the most recent migrations; if you need to test something old, dump your current development database and start with a fresh one based on an older `schema.rb`. Besides, if you really need an old migration then you can always dig it out of revision control or simply recreate it based on diffs between versions of `db/schema.rb` (or `db/structure.sql`).

Of course, if you don't keep `db/schema.rb` in revision control then you're doing it wrong and you a looming disaster on your hands.

For **(2)**, the `schema_migrations` table is very simple:

```
create table schema_migrations (
  version varchar not null primary key
)
```

So you can connect to PostgreSQL using `psql`, create the table by hand, and then do a bunch of `insert into schema_migrations (version) values (...)` to cover the historic migrations that should have been run in your staging environment, and then `db:migrate` as normal to get things up to date. Then you can spend as much time as you want doing a post mortem to figure out what happened to your staging database's `schema_migrations` table.

If you go this route, you might want to have a look at the `ar_internal_metadata` table if your version of Rails uses it.

You will, of course, backup your staging database before doing any of this. And you will want to examine your production database to make sure it isn't suffering the same problems.

Sometimes you have to get your hands dirty to make things go.